# Magento 2 Navigation Menu not showing

Tags: magento2, menu, navigation, topmenu

I am new to Magento so please bear with me :D

I have successfully created a theme that is a child to the blank theme.

I am trying to get the menu working and for the life of me cannot see why it is not showing. I have read a couple of other threads and no luck.

I have added a root category with my subcategories in it. I have then assigned it to the store settings. I have re-indexed the site, cleared cache and still no joy.

Am I doing the right thing by just adding a category and it will show?

Thanks

It seems I don't have the default category - see screenshot below

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have reinstalled Magento on my local machine. The menu shows fine on Luma and Blank theme but on my own custom one, it is not showing. Is there anything I need to include or check?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does the menu work on blank or Luma theme ?

Comment: Didn't try that. Just enabled the Luma theme and no it doesn't show. Any idea to why it is not showing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

You need to have all your  categories UNDER the **"Default Category"**. Then they should show.

[image]

**Solution 2 :**

Verify that **Default Category** Is Active **(Enable category = "yes")** and "**Include in Navigation Menu**" to **Yes**.

[image]

Clear your cache by running the **php bin/magento cache:clean** command and check it will works.

**Update :**

Just go to the Stores -> All Stores -> Click on Store (Main website store) - >You will see Root category option there listed with your category name -> select that one (Test,Collection whatever you want)->click on save and check.

**Refer below screenshot** :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I have checked and seems that I dont have the "Default Caregory". I have however added the Collections or Test Category as the "category name" under your solution 2. I have also made sure that enable category and include in menu is active.

See image that I have added in my question.

Any ideas to why I dont have default category and do I need it, if so - how can I get it ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried that before but did it again to check and still no joy. I am so lost to why this is happening :(

Comment: I am such a loss here. I have done exactly what you said. Made sure I have a root category, make sure that enable and include in menu is checked. I then made sure that it is included under store information. Cleaned cache, tried even the Luma theme and still no joy.

Do you know if I need to create or include a block in my theme, or check if it is in the Luma or Blank theme? I just dont know where to go from here.

Comment: Thanks. Did as you said and showing nothing still.. I just want to give up at this point :D

Comment: Thanks Dave for the help. I have done an update to my question - can you take a look?

Comment: @PeterWilkinson post you theme.xml code and theme register.php code , so that i can see what mistake you have done . Also check your custom theme is showing on backend -> Content -> Design->Configuration ?. Also delete above all comments so its easier to read you and others as well

Comment: I had the error, because I work with two websites and if I had to change the root of the category for the second website, it worked perfectly for me. Thank you -- Manthan Dave

Answer (score 5):

If you have tried all the other solutions and checked all the other basic things (enabled, correct root category...) then I might have the solution for you!

If the category was every removed from the menu ("Include in Menu" = "Off" in admin), and then turned back on; it seems there is a bug in Magento 2 here. Magento 2 will only set the "include_in_menu" attribute to 1 for the admin store and not any other front end stores, it will leave them as 0. So Magento thinks they are still disabled from the menu.

The solution is easy:

1. Figure out the attribute_id of the "include_in_menu" attribute; in my case, it's 69.
2. Figure out the entity_id of the category that you are working with; in my case its 47.
3. Look at the "catalog_category_entity_int" table for that category (entity_id) and attribute (attribute_id). Make sure "value"=1 for all the frontend stores. In my case store, 0 is an admin, and store 1 and 2 are two frontend stores.
4. Reindex and flush cache

Hope this works for you. It took me an hour to recreate a category structure, then when it happened again I dug into the code and found this. If it does work for you, give this answer an upvote. We use Magento 2 on our [GoToTags Store](https://store.gototags.com). The journey has been "fun" because of issues like this.

Good luck!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was it in my case, to find the appropriate row to change value to 1 I used SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'include_in_menu') AND entity_id = 3

Comment: Thanks for your answer similar issue.
Magento 2 will only set the "include_in_menu" attribute to 1 for the admin store and not any other front end stores, it will leave them as 0.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow solution given by "Manthan Dave" but still Navigation Menu not showing,Then check include_in_menu option for store level as suggested by "craig.tadlock"

[image: Magento 2 will only set the "include_in_menu" attribute to 1 for the admin store]

[image: But for other store views "include_in_menu" not set to yes]