# Unable to see Categories and Products I added on the frontend

Tags: magento2

Magento Version : 2.2.3

Steps :

1. Login as  Admin
2. Go to catalog and Add catagories
3. Then go to Products add products

PFA screenshots :

[image: Catogeory]
[image: Setting]
[image: product]
[image: product]

Answer (score 0):

You have added two categories that I can see from first two pictures. But in order to see navigation bar in menu you need to have categories UNDER the "Default Category". Then they should show.

Comment: Hey Tanvir ,  I tried what you said but did not work , Don't you think it doesn't  matter how you create your category  ?

Comment: This is a common mistake :). Please see here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154287/magento-2-navigation-menu-not-showing